# How do I make the PHP similar_text() function work for Japanese Characters (Kanji, Katakana and Hiragana)?

Tags: php, character-encoding, cjk, multibyte

I'm wanting to use the similar_text() function provided by PHP for Japanese characters. But unfortunately it is giving the wrong answer. How can I make it work?

For Example:
    `similar_text('土橋勇樹', '東日刷株式')`
gives the output 3, but we can clearly see it should be 0

Comment: This calculates the similarity between two strings as described in Programming Classics: Implementing the World's Best Algorithms by Oliver (ISBN 0-131-00413-1). Note that this implementation does not use a stack as in Oliver's pseudo code, but recursive calls which may or may not speed up the whole process. Note also that the complexity of this algorithm is O(N**3) where N is the length of the longest string.

Swapping the first and second may yield a different result; see the example below.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to handle the possible multibytes that are forming the Kanji characters. I am not 100% confident but I suspect similar_text does not support mb and you need a similar solution that can.

This links show peoples attempts at handling mb char similar to the php function.

https://gist.github.com/soderlind/74a06f9408306cfc5de9

https://github.com/antalaron/mb-similar-text

I have not personally tested this but the approach could be right or inspire you to write a custom function.

Also covered in this other post:

[how to use similar text php code in arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002690/how-to-use-similar-text-php-code-in-arabic)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've found that this link: https://github.com/antalaron/mb-similar-text provides the accurate implementation of mb_similar_text()